# An inverse Laplace transform involving Error function

Tags: laplace-transform, integral-transforms, special-functions, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Dear MOs,

I need to calculate the inverse Laplace transform of the following function

$$
g_a(z) = \frac{e^{a z}\: \text{erfc}(\sqrt{a z})}{\sqrt{z}-2},\quad a>0.
$$

I have checked, among many others, the book ["Table of Integral Transform, Vol. I"](http://books.google.ch/books?id=IPhQAAAAMAAJ&q=Table+of+Integral+Transforms,+Vol.+I&dq=Table+of+Integral+Transforms,+Vol.+I&hl=en&ei=U0_KT7yxNMv64QSSlXA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=book-thumbnail&redir_esc=y). In P.267, Eq. (14) is for

$$
g(z) = \frac{e^{a z}\: \text{erfc}(\sqrt{a z})}{\sqrt{z}}
$$

which is almost what I need. Other than this formula, I didn't find the one that I need. I have tried mathematica, which couldn't give an answer. I think the hope to find out the solution is quite small.

EIDT: here is some motivation of the problem.

Suppose the inverse transform gives us a function $f_a(t)$. I want to see the limit $$\lim_{a\rightarrow 0_+} f_a(t)=?$$

Can I simply do this:

$$
\lim_{a \rightarrow 0_+} \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(g_a\right)(t) \stackrel{?}{=}  \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\lim_{a\rightarrow 0_+} g_a\right)(t) = 
\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(g_0\right)(t) =\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi t}} +  2 e^{4t} \text{erfc}(-2\sqrt{t})
$$

Are there some Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorems to use in complex analysis?

Thank you very much for any hints!

Anand

Comment: Perhaps you may expand $(\sqrt{z}-2)^{-1}$ in powers of $z$ then
multiply by $e^{az} \text{erfc}(az)$ and apply Laplace transform to each term. The resulting terms  would be derivatives one of the others. Possibly obtain a not converging series
but maybe with some asymptotic properties. Or apply the same idea 
but expanding in powers of $z^{-1/2}$. 

The parameter a can be almost eliminated. This will simplify the computations.

Comment: Dear Professor Juan, I think it works by expanding in $z^{-1/2}$. Thanks a lot. I will try.


Comment: What exactly is it you want? A closed form? Asymptotics? Something you can evaluate numerically?

Comment: Dear Professor Igor Rivin, I add my motivation in my post above. 

Comment: Dear Professor Juan, I tried the hints you gave. It is not very easy. The pattern of the derivatives of $z^{-1/2}e^{az}\text{erfc}(\sqrt{az})$ is a little complicated. 

Comment: If you know the inverse transform of $g$, then you can get $g_a$ by a convolution, since $g_a(z)= (1-2 / \sqrt{z})^{-1} g(z)$, so you only need to find the inverse transform of $(1-2 / \sqrt{z})^{-1}$, which is an easy power series in $1/ \sqrt{z}$, then multiply. There's no guarantee that the resulting expression is particularly nice or useful, though.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "convolve" rather than "multiply", of course (Laplace transforms change convolution into multiplication).

Comment: Dear Zen Harper, thanks a lot. It works. After applying inverse Laplace transform of the two functions, I applied convolution, where I can use Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem to find the right limiting result. Thanks a lot! :-)
